# how to use two cognito user pools from two different aws accounts in my custom authorizer lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an aws account - **dev** where I am having a cognito user pool and a custom authorizer lambda running which authenticas users using client credentials grant flow using this user pool. All is working well at this moment.

Now I need to integrate a cognito user pool from another aws account (**test**) with dev account's custom authorizer so that users from test account can also be authenticated and authorized using the authorizer lambda in dev account.

I am thinking of creating a cross account IAM role in test account which will allow the authorizer lambda in dev account to assume it and be able to make a `describe_user_pool_client` call to test account's cognito service to fetch client_name.

```
app_client_details = cognito_idp_client.describe_user_pool_client(
        UserPoolId = cognito_user_pool_id,
        ClientId = client_id
    )

    client_name = app_client_details['UserPoolClient']['ClientName']

    client_name = client_name.split(' ')[0].lower()
```

Is there an alternate way of doing this or am I going in the right direction ?

### update

I have to keep using user pool in dev account and integrate user pool from account test. So combining these user pools (cross account access) is not an option.

Comment: You can use cross-account AWS Cognito Use Pools for a lambda authorizer. here you may find something useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453901/how-to-use-multiple-cognito-user-pools-for-a-single-endpoint-with-aws-api-gatewa
and here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-cross-account-cognito-authorizer.html

Comment: checked the links and found these not related to my use case. I have to use a custom lambda authorizer and support user pools from two different accounts. The links give details around cognito user pool authorize and not lambda authorizers.  I have to keep using the pool from account A and also support account B.
Am I missing something here ?